# Magento 2: Schema Changes for EE Catalog Staging

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, eav, catalog-staging

Does Magento 2's "EE Catalog Staging" feature rename the `entity_id` column of the `catalog_product_entity_datetime` table to `row_id`?

An old client recently reached out to me to say, after upgrading to Magento 2.1.1 with the EE Catalog Staging feature, that they're seeing the following errors related to some custom code.

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.entity_id' in 'field list'

and tell me their `catalog_product_entity_datetime` table's `entity_id` column is gone, replaced by a `row_id` column.

```
+--------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| value_id     | int(11)              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| attribute_id | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| store_id     | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| row_id       | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value        | datetime             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I"m (obviously) following up with my client on this one for more information -- but is this true?  Did Magento EE initiate a schema change here?

Comment: In which situation the entity_id and row_id are different ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Magento EE Staging modules change the schema on install. See: `app/code/Magento/CatalogStaging/Setup/InstallSchema.php` for datails.

Comment: Thank you @KAndy -- do you know if there's a reason for that?  Lacking context is seems — reckless — for a seemingly arbitrary change to tables that have been stable for more than half a decade.

Comment: Staging adds MVCC to product, category, rules, etc. entities. It adds row_id, created_in, updated_in to all entities. But because attribute value belongs to concrete version `entity_id` field was replaced on `row_id`.

Comment: In which situation the entity_id and row_id are different ?

Comment: entity_id and row_id are different when you have more than one version of an entity

Answer (score 7):

I can't reference the code on account of EE licensing, but in short: Yes. Magento Enterprise Edition 2.1.0 introduced a new 'content staging' feature, which involves some quite invasive changes to the core database schema.

Among other things, all `entity_id`/`product_id`/`child_id` columns in catalog_category_entity* and catalog_product_entity* tables are changed to `row_id`. There are similar changes across marketing-related content types. Staging covers categories, products, CMS, promotions, and more.

The changes are not arbitrary. They did not literally change `entity_id` to `row_id`. The entity IDs still exist, just in a different relation table. What they did was add a layer of abstraction such that changes (to any given content covered by the feature) can be batched and scheduled. You make content changes and add them to a batch, then at the appointed time Magento puts all of them live simultaneously. This is an evolution of some of the basic scheduling functionality that's been present for designs, banners, promo rules, etc. for a long time.

As to changing core table schemas to accomplish this, don't ask me why they chose this approach.

Comment: In which situation the entity_id and row_id are different ?

Comment: @devhs: If you use content staging for a record, you will have multiple rows with different row_ids but a shared entity_id.